# Django view "not" passing context to template for dynamically filled bootstrap dropdown-menu

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

I have a base template that includes another template for a drop down menu. If I hard code items for the li tag, it works fine. If I try to pass the objects.all(), it doesn't fill. Here's my setup:

**Model**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):  # Python 3: def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**View**

```
def dropdown_cats(request):
    cats = Category.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'home/dropdown-cats.html', {'cats': cats})
```

**home/base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles %}
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'media/logo.png' %}">

    <title>something.com</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'dist/css/bootstrap.css' %}" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link href="{% static 'dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="{% static 'dist/css/custom.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>
   <div id="site_wrapper" class="clearfix">
    <!-- Above-Nav
    ================================================== -->
        <div class="above-nav visible-desktop">
            <div class="container" style="text-align:center;">
                <a href={{home}}><img src="/static/media/webimages/frontpageheader.jpg" alt="something.com, click for home. "></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    <!--END above-nav
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Navbar   ==================================== -->
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href={{home}}>something.com</a>
                </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    {% block navbar %}
                    {% endblock navbar %}
                </ul>
          </div>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div><!-- navbar-inner -->
    </div>
    <!-- End Navbar =================================== -->
    <!-- Start Grid layout ============================ -->
    <!--<div class="container-fluid">-->
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row" style="text-align:center">
          <div class="col-xs-3"><h2>My Most Recent Blogs</h2>
              {% block left_side %}
              {% endblock left_side %}
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6">
              {% block middle %}
              {% endblock middle %}
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-3"><h2>Links</h2>
              {% block right_side %}
              {% endblock right_side %}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <!-- End Grid Layout   ====================== -->
    </div>
    <!-- close the wrapper ====================== -->
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'dist/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**home/home.html**

```
{% extends "home/base.html" %}

{% block navbar %}
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Categories<span  class="caret"></span></a>
                  {% include 'home/dropdown-cats.html' %}
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Previous Blogs</a></li>
              <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
              </form>
{% endblock navbar %}

{% block left_side %}
{% endblock left_side %}

{% block middle %}
{% endblock middle %}

{% block right_side %}
{% endblock right_side %}
```

**home/dropdown-cats.html**

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    {% if cats %}
        {% for cat in cats %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'category' cat.id %}">{{ cat.name }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        <li><a href="#">BAD TEST</a></li>
    {% endif %}
</ul>
```

If I test this by replacing the url tag in the for loop with something similar like GOOD TEST, there's still nothing inserted because cats is empty. All I get is one drop down entry "BAD TEST". I've used the shell to ensure Category.objects.all() returns the list as of categories as it should.

No idea how that Post statement got in the view there. Must have accidentally pasted it it. Anyways, I've excluded it from the view and included all my html for more details. I THINK I understand what you're saying Daniel, but I'm a bit confused. Isn't this how the tutorial modifies templates, by including it in the render parameters: render(request, 'template.html', dicts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really show enough information here, but I suspect you're getting confused about templates and views. Simply including another template doesn't "call" another view: the only thing that calls views is the URL handler. Templates themselves don't know anything about views.

If you want to dynamically add context for another template, you need to make it into a custom [inclusion tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#howto-custom-template-tags-inclusion-tags).

Comment: I understand now, Daniel. Thanks for the quick response. I'd vote ya up, but I am brand new to the community. Thanks again.

Comment: You can still accept the answer even with no reputation - you shoud do this anyway to let future searchers know that this solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Replace the snippet in your *Template* with:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    {% for cat in cats %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'category' cat.id %}">{{ cat.name }}</a></li>
    {% empty %}
        <li><a href="#">BAD TEST</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

The above will definitely work as long as the `cats` queryset as set in your *View* code has 1 or more items. The `for .. empty` template tag used in the template code above is documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for-empty).

Comment: Because it doesn't seem to be addressing the question at all. This does exactly the same as the original code, except it's slightly neater: but OP asked how to get the data for `cats` into the template in the first place.

Comment: @DanielRoseman (1) the question is not that easy to understand and I presumed the URL and context-to-template bindings are in place, and (2) it's not *slightly* neater, it's *neater*. If I have confidence in my answer I leave it up to the OP to decide which is the better answer, rather than downvoting a not-so-good-but-still-helpful answer.